# Perl multiline regex replace from CLI

Tags: regex, perl

I want to permanently enable a Linux repo from the command line in a file that contains the definitions of multiple repos. So the file looks something like :

```
[repo-first]
some config line
another config line
enabled=0
more config lines

[repo-second]
some config line
another config line
enabled=0
more config lines
```

I want to be able to selectively set 'enable=0' to 'enable=1' based on the repo name.

There seem to be multiple ways of sucking in the file and/or ignoring the line separator including -p0e, -0777, "BEGIN {undef $}...". My best guess so far is something like :

```
perl -0777 -e -pi "BEGIN { undef $/ } s/(\[repo\-first\]\n(.*\n)*?enabled\=)0/$1\1/mg" /etc/yum.repos.d/repo-def-file
```

But naturally, this doesn't work. Ideas?

Comment: If the repo configs are separated with a blank line, you can use paragraph mode to good effect `-00`. E.g. `perl -00 -pi -e"next unless /\Q[repo-first]/; s/^enabled=\K0/1/m;" file`. Though I have to say that Borodin's answer will work much better.

Comment: Also `-0777` and `BEGIN { undef $/ }` are mutually exclusive, as they do the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained, a regex is generally the wrong approach, but it does have the advantage of retaining the order and structure of the file

So if you must, then this will do the job

```
perl -0777 -i -pe's/\[repo-first\][^[]+enabled=\K\d+/1/' repo-def-file
```

Answer (score 3):

It would be much more convenient to use a module, such as [`Config::Tiny`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Tiny)

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::Tiny;

my $conf = Config::Tiny->read( 'repo-def-file' );
$conf->{'repo-first'}{enabled} = 1;
$conf->write( 'repo-def-file' );
```

Comment: That's easy, but this is for a system setup script in a hosted environment, so, unfortunately, it has to be command line.

Comment: @JimmyZoto `perl /path/to/script` (even in a shared hosting environment you can write to files, can't you?) If that doesn't work, `perl -MConfig::Tiny -we'my $conf = Config::Tiny->read('repo-def-file'); $conf->{'repo-first'}{enabled} = 1;
$conf->write('repo-def-file');` Alternatively, store the argument to `-e` in a heredoc in the setup script.

Comment: Probably. But it requires a dependency (which my distro, barebones CentOS, doesn't have by default) and it's actually longer on the command line by quite a bit. In code, using Tiny is *much* more readable, but for this particular case, I think the regex is preferable.